# javax.xml.rpc does not exist - maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, soap, soap-client

I'm using IntelliJ and I'm working on a **Maven** project. I've imported a **SOAP** Web Service. When I run my project, I recieve a **"java: package javax.xml.rpc does not exist."** error. I've researched the error and tried to add new dependencies about this xml but IntelliJ couldn't find these dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have in pom dependency like

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.rpc/javax.xml.rpc-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After that in your IntelliJ on the right side of the maven menu, go maven clean, and then go, maven, install ( or from your terminal you can go mvn clean install ), which will pull fresh dependencies again.
Or, from what I remember there is a trick to just add a dependency, add any code change in your intellij pom.xml and IntelliJ will automatically offer you to pull dependencies, but not sure if that is enabled in your IDE.

Comment: Refreshing my project is worked! Thank you so much :)